# Trouble using ant length condition on a string

Tags: ant

I'm trying to deal with a string that has a long error message instead of a short value when something goes wrong. My ant script contains the following code:

```
<!-- build.svnversion is invalid if it's longer than 15 characters --> 
<length property="build.svnversion.length" string="${build.svnversion}" />
<echo message="build.svnversion.length: ${build.svnversion.length}"/>

<condition property="build.svnversion" value="N/A" else="${build.svnversion}">
    <length string="${build.svnversion}" when="gt" length="15" />
</condition>
<echo message="build.svnversion: ${build.svnversion}" />
```

This produces the following output:

```
[echo] build.svnversion.length: 148
[echo] build.svnversion: svn: The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
[echo] working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
[echo] working copy.
```

Why isn't build.svnversion getting set to N/A since its length is clearly greater than 15?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you attempting to reset the property `build.svnversion`?

Once a property is set, it cannot be unset or changed<sup>1</sup>.

In your `<condition/>` task, you'll have to use another property name.

```
<!-- build.svnversion is invalid if it's longer than 15 characters --> 
<length property="build.svnversion.length"
    string="${build.svnversion}" />

<echo message="build.svnversion.length: ${build.svnversion.length}"/>

<condition property="real.build.svnversion"
    value="N/A"
    else="${build.svnversion}">
    <length string="${real.build.svnversion}"
        when="gt" length="15" />
</condition>
<echo message="real.build.svnversion: ${real.build.svnversion}" />
```

---

<sup>1.</sup>. You can use Ant-Contrib's `<var/>` task to change a property's value or to completely unset it, but that's considered bad form.

Comment: Thanks. This was problem.  Didn't realize that you couldn't change a property value once set.  Unfortunaely, I can't vote for your solution without more reputation points.

Comment: @StevenHB You don't have to _vote_ for a solution. You _accept_ the solution. There should be an outline of a check mark to the left of the answer. Select it, and it turns green.